# Constructing multi-level object tree with manual dependency injection

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am working on refactoring a Java application that I wrote. At the time of writing the original, I made some poor design decisions, and am now suffering the consequences. In particular, the code is nearly impossible to unit test, and dependencies are all over the place.

I have been doing a lot of reading about design patterns and good OO-design principles (including SOLID). I think the key to solving my problems lies in the following: constructor dependency injection (ideally NOT via a framework like Spring; I'd rather stick to plain old Java), factories, builders, and good OO-design in general.

Without getting into too many specifics, imagine I have an object structure where O1 has one or more O2 child objects, and each O2 object has one or more O3 child objects, and so on. So, essentially, O1 is a parent of O2, and O2 is a parent of O3. (But not in the inheritance sense.)

The dependencies I want to represent are of the *child to the parent*. So, for example, injecting the dependencies into the constructor might result in something like this:

```
// highest-level object; no dependencies
O1 o1a = new O1();

// second-level objects; depend on highest-level object
O2 o2a = new O2(o1a);
O2 o2b = new O2(o1a);

// 3rd-level objects; depend on second-level objects
O3 o3a = new O3(o2a); // dependency on o2a
O3 o3b = new O3(o2a); // dependency on o2a
O3 o3c = new O3(o2b); // dependency on o2b
```

OK, so that in itself is simple enough. But there are some complicating factors:

- Each of these objects is potentially quite complex to construct (some involve the parsing of schemas and the building of in-memory object models associated with the objects);
- I won't know at compile time how many of each object will be required (this is configuration dependent); as such, manually coding dependencies (as above) is not an option;
- I don't want to "new" specific classes, because I want the code to be extensible, and want to be able to "stub" in different versions for testing; (factories?);
- I need to be able to start the creation process at the "lowest level"; for example, I may know at run-time that I need to create a specific O3 object; to do this requires determining O3's "parent" (O2), and then O2's parent (O1), then creating O1, creating O2 (injecting newly-created O1), creating O3 (injecting newly-created O2), etc.
- I might also, potentially, want to keep track of objects so that they can be reused; so, in the example above, o3a and o3b both make use of o2a; if o2a was created in the course of creating o3a, I'd want to reuse the same object when creating o3b.

In all my reading of design patterns, unfortunately, I have never seen any example of how to accomplish something even vaguely like this. (All examples are quite simple by comparison.)

I have wondered about creating some sort of factory or builder for O3, and passing it an instance of a factory or builder for O2. That instance of O2 factory or builder would, in turn, have been created with an instance of a factory or builder for O1. But I'm not sure if this is the right approach, and even if it is, I'm struggling to get much beyond the high-level concept.

I would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to accomplish all of this in a clean, maintainable, extensible way. It's a bit of a tall order, I know.

Thanks in advance,
Greg

Answer (score 3):

I started out with basically the same problems as you are. I wanted a pure Java "Injection" solution without magic, so I created [JayWire](https://github.com/vanillasource/jaywire). Even if you don't plan to use this library, you may want to look at the [Wiki](https://github.com/vanillasource/jaywire/wiki) for some ideas.

Specifically, the basic idea was to inject factories (java.util.function.Supplier) instead of constructed objects. That way, the consuming class does not have to know whether the object is a singleton, pooled, or constructed every time (new). It goes like this:

```
public class O3 {
    private Supplier<O2> o2Supplier;

    public O3(Supplier<O2> o2Supplier) {
        this.o2Supplier = o2Supplier;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
        // Here O3 wants an O2 instance, but does not
        // need to know how to construct it, or even
        // whether its constructed, or the same instance
        // is re-used.
        O2 o2 = o2Supplier.get();
        o2.doIt(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

This way the hierarchy is "hidden" from O3, it only knows it needs O2, but doesn't necessarily need to know how O2 is constructed.

You can of course change Supplier to Factory (or whatever), although a Factory implies it will always create a new instance.

You even might have some parameters at the construction of O2 that are local, but still want to hide the fact that it needs O1 from the consumer O3. This can also be done this way:

```
public class O3 {
    private Supplier2<String, Integer, O2> o2Supplier;

    public O3(Supplier2<String, Integer, O2> o2Supplier) {
        this.o2Supplier = o2Supplier;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
        // Here O3 wants an O2 instance again, but also
        // wants additional parameters for its construction.
        O2 o2 = o2Supplier.get("Param1", 5);
        o2.doIt(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Supplier2 is similar to a Supplier, it only takes 2 additional parameters to its get() method.

This way, O3 still does not know that O2 needs O1, so the hierarchy can be broken up. You may want to look at "Propagating Dependencies" in the Wiki.

JayWire enables all this, and also helps you create these Suppliers easily.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Good stuff. (And I'll check out JayWire.) As it happens, I have basically used this approach -- having factories which are constructed with dependencies on factories that know how to construct/fetch parent level objects, etc. It seems to be working out well so far. Again, thanks for the info. (I would up-vote, but don't have enough reputation to do so yet. Sorry.)

Answer (score 1):

So I have a solution I use for quickly being able to do swapping of implementation classes for a set of interfaces.

I -think- you -might- be able to make use of the code to make 'defaults' for your different POJOs, etc.

It is Made up of 3 classes, 1 'interface Module', 1 'class ModuleImpl', and 1 (or more) Factory class that builds the configurations.

I haven't tried this code, but I think it would work for allowing you to both have default constructors and Injected constructors.

Module.java (You'll need to add your package info)

```
public interface Module {

    /**
     * 
     * This method returns the component that is bound to a given type.
     * 
     * @param type
     *            - type type of component to retrieve
     * @return
     */
    public <T> T getComponent(Class<T> type);

    /**
     * 
     * Bind a component to a type.
     * 
     * @param type
     *            - the type to bind the component to
     * @param component
     *            - the object instance to associate with the type key
     */
    public <T> void setComponent(Class<T> type, T component);

}
```

ModuleImpl.java (You'll need to add your package info)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ModuleImpl implements Module {

    private final Map<Class<?>, Object> mMapping = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> T getComponent(Class<T> type) {
        // We are the only ones putting things into this map so we're guaranteed
        // type safety.
        return (T) mMapping.get(type);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void setComponent(Class<T> type, T component) {
        mMapping.put(type, component);
    }

}
```

Here is the Factory for Configuration(s) By Default this is great for 'system wide' configuration

```
public class ConfigurationModuleFactory {

    public static Module makeDefaultConfiguration() {
        final Module module = new ModuleImpl();
        module.setComponent(<SomeInterfaceA>.class, new <ConcreteClassA>());
        module.setComponent(<SomeInterfaceB>.class, new <ConcreteClassB>());
        module.setComponent(<SomeInterfaceC>.class, new <ConcreteClassC>());
        module.setComponent(<SomeInterfaceD>.class, new <ConcreteClassD>());
        return module;
    }

    public static Module makeSomeCustomConfiguration() {
        final Module module = new ModuleImpl();
        module.setComponent(<SomeInterfaceA>.class, new <ConcreteClassA2>());
        module.setComponent(<SomeInterfaceB>.class, new <ConcreteClassB2>());
        module.setComponent(<SomeInterfaceC>.class, new <ConcreteClassC2>());
        module.setComponent(<SomeInterfaceD>.class, new <ConcreteClassD2>());
        return module;
    }

    /// BIT OF REDUNDANCY BELOW HERE, but... There are a few different ways you can do this, I'm just showing a couple variations. 

    private static Module configuration = makeDefaultConfiguration();

    public static Module getModuleConfiguration() {
        if (configuration == null) {
            // This also allows the configuration for the entire application to
            // be changed by altering this line only
            configuration = makeTestConfiguration();
        }
        return configuration;
    }

}
```

Here is something you 'could' do....

Make a module config for each class

```
public class ConfigurationModuleFactory {

    public static Module 03_default() {
        final Module module = new ModuleImpl();
        module.setComponent(02Interface.class, new 02());
        return module;
    }
    public static Module 02_default() {
        final Module module = new ModuleImpl();
        module.setComponent(01Interface.class, new 01());
        return module;
    }
}
```

If you decided to store Class Instances within 03, etc.

```
public class 03{

    02 m02 = null;

    public 03(){
        // get the generator configuration Module
        Module configuration = ConfigurationModuleFactory.03_default();
        // get the appropriate class instances
        m02 = configuration.getComponent(02Interface.class);

    }

    public 03(02 02Instance){
        m02 = 02Instance;
    }

}
```

Or store an interface in the classes

```
public class 03{

    02Interface m02 = null;

    public 03(){
        // get the generator configuration Module
        Module configuration = ConfigurationModuleFactory.03_default();
        // get the appropriate class instances
        m02 = configuration.getComponent(02Interface.class);
    }

    public 03(02Interface 02Instance){
        m02 = 02Instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm definitely going to give this some thought. (Not allowed to upvote yet, or I would.)